# How to solve Linked list found cycle error

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

The code below is written to solve [Rotate List](https://leetcode.com/problems/rotate-list/) problem in leetcode, but my code is throwing "Found cycle in the ListNode" error.
I can't find which line is creating the cycle, help!

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution(object):
  def rotateRight(self, head, k):
    """
    :type head: ListNode
    :type k: int
    :rtype: ListNode
    """
    # visualiser   =    prev -> curr -> nxt
    # ListNode [1,2,3]   2       3      None


    dummy = prev = ListNode(0, head)   #create a new node, its next node = head
    curr, nxt = head, head.next
    while curr and k > 0: 
        if nxt == None:
            prev.next = nxt
            curr.next = dummy.next
            dummy.next = curr
            k -= 1
        else:
            prev = prev.next
            curr = curr.next
            nxt = nxt.next
    return dummy.next
```

Answer (score 1):

The `if nxt == None:` block performs the first rotation correctly, but at the second rotation things go wrong. At that time `prev` and `curr` still reference the nodes they referenced at the first rotation so that now `curr` is the **first** node of the linked list. But that means the statement `curr.next = dummy.next` creates a self-reference!

A visualisation may help. Just before the first rotation occurs, we have this state:

```
dummy            prev curr  nxt
   ↓               ↓   ↓     ↓
   0 → 1 → 2 → 3 → 4 → 5 → None
```

After the first rotation, we have this:

```
dummy curr           prev   nxt
   ↓   ↓               ↓     ↓
   0 → 5 → 1 → 2 → 3 → 4 → None
```

This is also the state before the second rotation starts. The cycle is introduced when `curr.next = dummy.next` is executed:

```
dummy curr           prev   nxt
   ↓   ↓               ↓     ↓
   0 → 5 ┐ 1 → 2 → 3 → 4 → None
       └─┘
```

Any further rotation will not modify the list anymore. What you really would have  wanted is that the combo `prev, curr` would take a "step back", but that is not easily done, as we don't have a reference to the predecessor of `prev`. So in short, we need a different approach.

To be honest, a dummy node is not helpful for this problem.

There should be no need to perform `k` times an update to `next` attribute(s). This can be done by mutating only two nodes. The main idea is to make the list circular and then set the `head` reference to one of the other nodes (depending on `k`) and then break the cycle again. Also, make sure to reduce *huge* values of `k` by realising that all-around rotations are useless. For instance, in a list of 5 nodes, doing 721 rotations has the same result as doing 1 rotation.

Here is an implementation:

```
class Solution(object):
  def rotateRight(self, head, k):
    # boundary case
    if not head or not head.next:
      return head
   
    # get tail and size of list
    tail = head
    size = 1
    while tail.next:
      size += 1
      tail = tail.next

    # temporarily make list circular
    tail.next = head

    # get the node that will be the new tail
    tail = head
    for _ in range(size - k%size - 1):
      tail = tail.next

    # break cycle after new tail
    head = tail.next
    tail.next = None

    return head
```